# Unknown RR type in bind zone file [CENTOS 7]

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, unix

I am experimenting with Bind at the moment and setting up an pimary dns on Centos 7.

The settings have been configured accordingly and adjusted to what i want. But i am recieving error upon start bind and named.

The error i am encountering from **journalctl -xe**:

```
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: /etc/named/db.reverse.a18zagbi.zone:4: unknown RR type '86400'
```

**Down below is full journalctl -xe output:**

```
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone a18zagbi.local/IN: loaded serial 2011071001
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/named/db.reverse.a18zagbi.zone:2: near eol: unexpected end of input
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: /etc/named/db.reverse.a18zagbi.zone:4: unknown RR type '86400'
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone 11.204.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file /etc/named/db.reverse.a18zagbi.zone failed: unexpected end of input
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: zone 11.204.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: _default/11.204.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: unexpected end of input
```

**/etc/named.conf**:

```
options {
listen-on port 53 { any; };
directory "/var/named";
dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
allow-query { any; };
allow-recursion { 10.222.1.0/24; 127.0.0.0/8; };
bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};
logging { channel default_debug { file "data/named.run"; severity dynamic; }; };
zone "." IN { type hint; file "named.ca"; };
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/named/named.conf.local";
```

**/etc/named/named.conf.local**

```
zone "a18zagbi.local" {

    type master;
    file "/etc/named/db.firstzone.a18zagbi.local";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "11.204.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/db.reverse.a18zagbi.zone";

};
```

**db.firstzone.a18zagbi.local**:

```
$ttl 1D

@ IN SOA ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se. root.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se. (
        2011071001  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

; Name Servers - NS records
    IN NS   ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se.

;name Servers - A records

ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se IN A 10.204.11.119


; Other servers
```

**db.reverse.a18zagbi.zone**

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA     ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se. root.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se.
(
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers
      IN      NS      ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se.

; PTR records

119.11  IN  PTR     ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se. ; 10.204.11.119
```

*I searched on StackExchange, but it is pretty hard for me to apply due to not being encountered the same error and please in any case.*

**Thank you enormously and how shall I proceed from here.?**

Note:
 If you will just come by my thread to bash me and throwing accusations that i have not done my research, please leave this thread instead enlighten me with the knowledge instead that i am hungry of. :)

Comment: The error you referenced is the second error you're getting.  The one right before it tells you exactly where the problem is: `mar 04 20:51:32 ns1.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se bash[9599]: dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/named/db.reverse.a18zagbi.zone:2: near eol: unexpected end of input`.  Compare the working zone and the erroring zone.  In the erroring one you have the left parenthesis on a new line.  It shouldn't be on a new line.

Comment: @yoonix I see and thank you very much. I moved the pharenthesis and removed some whitespaces and it worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use the `named-checkzone` command to double check the format and syntax of your zones before starting your BIND nameserver. It should tell you exactly where and what fails.